# Edit is Adding database record - not updating the record

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had this code working - then I added the ability to add or update an image from the edit function - not when I add an image and try to update the sql record - it adds a new record. Here is the controller code for the edit. ANy ideas?

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var Emp = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (Emp == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(Emp);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Employee employee, HttpPostedFileBase image1)
    {

        try

        {
            if (image1 != null)
            {
                employee.Image = new byte[image1.ContentLength];
                image1.InputStream.Read(employee.Image, 0, image1.ContentLength);
            }
            db.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `employee` have a key property, such as an `ID`?  If so, what is the value for that property when you debug?

Comment: Are you certain that the entity has the ID passed in along inside it?

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new to all this. What is the best way to debug that? The PK is ID for employee

Comment: Before I added the image upload - the edit worked fine, Using:         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Employee employee)
        {
            
            try

            {
                db.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

Comment: @EBaze: Place a debugging breakpoint in the method and run the application in debug.  When the method is reached the debugger should stop there and you can examine your variables, step through the code line by line, etc.

Comment: Unrelated side note: An empty `catch` is a *famously* bad idea.  You're basically telling your code, "If anything goes wrong, I don't want to know about it."  Someday when you find yourself asking "What's going wrong?", that's your answer.

Comment: I tried to put a breakpoint at db.SaveChanges(); on the controller, but it did not stop.

Comment: @EBaze: Then either it's not actually reaching that action method, or your debugging setup is misconfigured in some way.  For the former, check what other action methods it might be reaching.  For the latter, there isn't much we can do within the scope of this question.  You might start with some Google searches for how to debug ASP.NET MVC applications.  If a breakpoint can't be hit then the debugger usually has a message indicating why.

Comment: @EBaze: Or a third option... the debugger may not reach that line because the code fails *before* that line.  In which case it would fail silently (by your design) and return the view.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: @David - OK I added a bread point at the  db.SaveChanges(); on the Create action result and is stops. So for some reason it is using the create and not the edit?

Comment: @EBaze: Then that means your form is posting to the create action.  You're on the right track, and have identified that the problem isn't in the code you're showing in the question.  Continue to trace the source of the problem.  If you encounter something unexpected, we can help with that.

Comment: Yep. It was completely my fault. using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", was using (Html.BeginForm("Create",

Thanks for the help!